# Potential due to a continuous charge distribution on ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

> Derive the formula for the potential at point $P(0,0,z)$ directly above the center of a ring of charge with radius $R$ and uniform charge density $\lambda$.

My attempt:
Since $$\lambda= \frac{Q}{R}=\frac{dq}{2\pi R}$$, I derived $$dV=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\frac{\lambda 2\pi R}r$$. But from here, I don't how to fit P into my formula, do I replace r with z?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: To switch between r and z I believe you're looking for the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: "Above the center" only makes sense when we know the orientation of the ring. Is this in the plane of the ring and off axis, or on the axis of the ring but out of the plane? It makes a difference... A diagram is almost always helpful.

Comment: @Floris The question doesn't come with a picture, it just say the ring in on the x-y plane, and P is above the ring with (0,0,z)

Comment: @AlanSE But the problem doesn't give an angle, should I just assume a theta?

Comment: @SSS Since you know the point is directly above the center of the ring, you should be able to construct a right triangle. This eliminates the need to know any angle, as reflected in the equation a^2+b^2=c^2

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing is parametrizating a ring. For instance, this is a ring: $\gamma(t) = R(\cos t, \sin t)$. Actually it is a circunference of radius $R$. It is charged with linear density $\lambda$.

The potential in the point $P(0, 0, z)$ is 
$$dV = \frac{kdq}{r} = \frac{k\lambda d\gamma}{r}$$
where $r$ is the distance between an element of charge $dq$ and $P$. Since $dq$ is located at the ring $\gamma$, we have: $r = |P - \lambda(t)| = |(R\sin t, R\cos t, -z)| = \sqrt{R^2 + z^2}$.

Therefore, integrating all over the ring, the potential: 
$$
V(z) = \int_\gamma \frac{k\lambda d\gamma}{|P - \lambda(t)|} = 
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{k\lambda}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}Rdt
$$

Now the problem reduces to solve this integral, which is very trivial as you can see:
$$
V(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{k\lambda R}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}dt = 
\frac{k\lambda R}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi} dt = 
\frac{k\lambda R}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}} 2\pi
$$

Since $2\pi R$ is the length of the ring, we have: $2\pi R\lambda = Q$. Therefore:
$$
V(z) = \frac{kQ}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The ring can be parameterized by ${\bf r}' = R \left(\cos \theta \ \hat{\bf x} + \sin \theta \ \hat{\bf y}\right)$. Noting that
$$
\left|d{\bf r}'\right| = R d\theta \left|\left(-\sin \theta \ \hat{\bf x} + \cos \theta \ \hat{\bf y}\right)\right| = R d\theta
$$
and
$$
{\bf r} - {\bf r'} = \left(x-R\cos\theta\right) \ \hat{\bf x} + \left(y-R\sin\theta\right) \ \hat{\bf y} + z \ \hat{\bf z},
$$
the potential at ${\bf r} = x \ \hat{\bf x} + y \ \hat{\bf y} + z \ \hat{\bf z}$ is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi\left({\bf r}\right) &=& k \int \left|d{\bf r}'\right| \frac{\lambda\left({\bf r}'\right)}{\left|{\bf r} - {\bf r'}\right|} \\
\phi\left(x,y,z\right) &=& k \lambda R \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{1}{\left[\left(x-R\cos\theta\right)^2 + \left(y-R\sin\theta\right)^2 + z^2\right]^{1/2}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
For the specific case $x=y=0$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi\left(0,0,z\right) &=& k \lambda R \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{1}{\left(R^2 + z^2\right)^{1/2}} \\
&=& \frac{k Q}{\left(R^2 + z^2\right)^{1/2}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
with $Q = 2 \pi R \lambda$ the total charge.